JMeter - How to dynamically create/capture new test data for every run for a MS Sql Server / Oracle DB
I was wondering if it was a good choice to movie away from CSV file because we currently are using the same test data over and over.
I was wondering if it was possible with the JDBC connection configuration if it was a good idea to use to be able to capture this data.
Assuming it's a pre-processor, I am assuming there may be some file i/o load since it would be reading from the database but how big of an issue is this?
I am guessing that I could capture the data and write functions to the parameters that I need to fill in to grab the correct new/test data. Please let me know how to go about this.

Normally people use the same test data because they want their tests to be repeatable
If you cannot or don't want to do it for whatever reason you can query the database and fetch the new test data, however I wouldn't do it in a PreProcessor. Although PreProcessors execution time is not included into response time, it will still count and result in lower throughput.
So I would suggest obtaining "fresh" test data somewhere in setUp Thread Group and save it into a CSV file via i.e. Flexible File Writer
